# How to insert text as date into cell in google script? (with compliance to timezones conversions)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am parsing CSV files. One field is a text string in a 2016-01-20 17:40:37 format. It should look like this while displayed in the sheet.
Script has a timezone +9. Spreadsheet has a timezone +10. How do I do it?

*I can get:*

```
tsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()
tscript=Session.getScriptTimeZone()
```

*And I can use:*

```
Utilities.formatDate(datetime, timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

*But I don't understand how to do it exactly.*

For now my code is:

```
date = "2016-01-20"                         //after regex parsing
time = "17:40:37"                           //after regex parsing
datetime = new Date(""+date + "T" + time+"Z")
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(datetime).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Result in the cell is: 
21/01/2016 3:40:37.

Expected to be the same as input (the same time and date without timezone shift):
2016-01-20 17:40:37
, but in the Date format to be able to sort/make date related calculations in spreadsheet.

I need only to take a text string from an external source and make it a date in a spreadsheet cell (without regard for which time zone has been selected in settings). The representation must be the same/the same day/the same hours. Not the same epoch.

Edit:

It looks like if I use

```
 sheet.getRange('A2').setValue("2016-01-20 17:40:37").setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

it works. Is this the right solution?

Comment: If you show your code, people would be better capable of giving your suggestions. As it stands right now, there are various options available but correction option or suggestion is dependent on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Utilities. I have used the below line of code to print the time stamp in the cell.

```
.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6:30", "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"));
```